# How do I clear all data in a MySQL database while maintaining the table structures?

Tags: linux, mysql

Using MySQL CLI, how can I remove all data in a given MySQL database without changing any table's structures?

Comment: This is in Linux by the way.

Comment: Have you tried `delete * from *` just off the top of my head.

Comment: That works for a single table, not all

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`truncate`
example:

```
truncate table friends
```

– will delete all records from the table and also rebuild the table, thus resetting the auto_increment counter.

Comment: can you truncate an entire database, or do you have to go table by table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912813/truncate-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-in-one-command

Comment: That works for a single table, not all

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like you want TRUNCATE.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html

Comment: That works for a single table, not all